# how to get data from 4 tables using joins

Tags: mysql, database

I am getting data from two tables using following query it works fine but i want to get also from two more mean 4 tables

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ml.UserID,ml.ContentAddedDateTime,cat.ContentType,cat.ContentTitle,cat.ContentSource,cat.ContentDescription
  FROM LibraryMaster as ml
  LEFT JOIN CatalogMaster cat ON cat.CatalogID=ml.CatalogID");
```

i want to take category From CategoryLookUp and subCategoryTitle from SubCategoryLook

here is the CatalogMaster Table

```
    CatalogID   int(11)         No      auto_increment                          
CategoryID  int(11)         No                                  
SubCategoryID   int(11)         No                                  
ContentType varchar(10) utf8_general_ci     No                                  
ContentTitle    varchar(25) utf8_general_ci     No                                  
AddedByUserID   int(11)         No                                  
ContentDescription  varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL                                
ContentSource   varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci     No                                  
ContentAddedDateTime
```

here is the CatgeoryLookUp

```
    CategoryID  int(11)         No      auto_increment                          
CategoryTitle   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No                                  
CategoryDescription varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL                                
CategoryAddedByUserID   int(11)         No                                  
CategoryAddedDateTime
```

here is the SubCatLookUp

```
    SubCategoryID   int(11)         No      auto_increment                          
LinkedCategoryID    int(11)         No                                  
SubCategoryTitle    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No                                  
SubCategoryAddedDateTime    timestamp       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                               
SubCategoryAddedByUserID
```

Comment: And what is that you have trouble with?

Comment: Show your table structure.

Comment: provide table structures and relations

Comment: I have given tables updated please see update post

Comment: check updated question i have given tables.

Comment: @JawAli I have seen that and on the basis of that below is your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("
            SELECT ml.UserID, ml.ContentAddedDateTime, cat.ContentType, cat.ContentTitle, cat.ContentSource, cat.ContentDescription, clu.CategoryTitle, sclu.SubCategoryTitle
               FROM LibraryMaster as ml
                    LEFT JOIN CatalogMaster cat ON cat.CatalogID=ml.CatalogID
                    LEFT JOIN CategoryLookUp clu ON cat.CategoryID = clu.CategoryID
                    LEFT JOIN SubCatLookUp sclu ON cat.SubCategoryID = sclu.SubCategoryID
");
```

Use above query,

Comment: there is no CatalogID in CategoryLookUp and you have used joined

Comment: @JawAli this is not `CatalogID`, check again this is `CategoryID`.